# How to take n numbers as input in single line in Python

Tags: python, input, user-input

Like in C++ how can I ask user input upto a range

**Below is the code to take user input in c++**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int array[50];
    cin>>n;
    //ask a list
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cin>>array[i];
    }
}
```

How can I ask user input like above in Python 3? (I don't want to take the inputs in different lines)

Answer (score 4):

This will convert numbers separated by spaces to be stored in ar:

```
ar = list(map(int, input().strip().split(' ')))
```

Strip() is used to remove all the leading and trailing spaces from a string, so that it is clear and easy to classify/distinguish inputs.

Answer (score 4):

The following snippet will map the single line input separated by white space into list of integers

```py
lst = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(lst)
```

Output:

```sh
$ python test.py
1 2 3 4 5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are various methods to do this.
User can enter multiple inputs in single line separated by a white space. Let's say I want user to enter 5 numbers as

> 1 2 3 4 5

This will be entered in a single line. But keep in mind that any input is considered a string in python. So you'll have to convert these values into integer values. Also, you would need to access these entered values separately. For that, you can convert the values to integer and add them into list. In python, strangely enough, there are no arrays, but lists. 
So your code should look something like this:

```
mylist=list(map(int,input("Enter 5 numbers: ").split())
```

You might want to look at implementation of `split()` and `map()` functions. You can find them in the official documentation. But here is a little explanation:
The `map(func,seq)` function will convert the input one by one to the function supplied, int in this case. This function is equivalent to a for  loop which iterates over the elements one by one  and applies some transformation function. The `split()` function will split the input by white spaces if no separator is supplied in the brackets. By default, map() function returns a map object. So to convert it into a list, we use `list()`.

Hope this clarifies your doubt.

Comment: but can it be done within for loop? The variable should take input even the user press enter or in the same line like in c,c++

Answer (score 2):

To input an array of known length:

```py
n = int(input())                                # for size
Array = list(map(int, input().split(' ')[:n]))  # to input n elements
print(Array)
```

Answer (score 0):

To enter the numbers in one line and in limits

```
limit = int(input("Enter your limit : "))

arr = list(map(int,input(""Enter your number : ").split()[:limit]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 5  # here only five inputs taken from user
arr = list(map(int, input().split()[:n]))
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

these line of code will also works the same u dont need a split argument as per i saw in some ide like online compiler and some of that ide of codechef and hackerearth

```
list1=list(map(int,input()))
```

Comment: How will this work? Other answers use variants of `input().split()` which outputs a list of strings that can be converted to `int` with `map`. In your answer, the output from `input()` will be a single string, so it's essentially the same as `list1=int(input())`